# Please help me !! - Missing Notes

Tags: iphone, mac, icloud, backup, notes.app

So a few days ago, I got a MacBook and set it up— next thing I knew 200-300 notes were missing and some notes that I do have, have some or all content missing. And then, some of the folders I have (the notes missing were part of folders inside a folder) were put in its previous state aka the ones that had the missing notes. I did everything, like resyncing, I have good storage in my iCloud and devices so it isn’t a storage problem either. I even contacted apple SEVERAL times and none of what they said worked.. I heard I could do a backup, but my last backup was 10 weeks ago and I don’t want to lose all of my notes. Please, I really need help!! These notes are very important to me and I really need them back. Keep in mind that this whole fiasco happened in a iCloud folder. Any ideas how I can get them back?

Comment: With notes you mean entries in the Notes app? How did you restore them onto your new Mac?

Comment: Yes! They were in an iCloud folder— What do you exactly mean by restore?

Comment: And these notes, they were in your iCloud storage?  They aren't in some other account that is synced to whatever device you created them on?

Comment: Yes! And they aren’t in some other account that is synced to my phone

Comment: Are the notes missing when you try to view them in the iCloud Notes web page?

Comment: Yes, the notes are missing in the web page too.

Comment: I don't think anyone has asked... are the notes still on the original device?

Comment: They aren’t sadly

Comment: Then it‘s probably time to restore them from the most recent backup.

Comment: Are you sure? Last time I backuped was 10 weeks ago and all the notes didn’t exist then

Comment: If these notes are not on any of your devices, not accessible via iCloud and also not on your most recent backup, there aren‘t a lot of options left, unfortunately.

Comment: Ohh, alright, thank you so much for your help!